# Who uses syslog for logging their web application

Tags: logging, syslog

I was wondering if somebody use syslog to log his web application errors/warning/info ? It could be quite useful in a deployment environment with a lot of servers.

If yes, what kind of client visualisation you can get to watch errors and grouping the same errors into batch?

Do you use other techniques than syslog to achieve this kind of logging functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I use this viewer: http://www.kiwisyslog.com/

I use syslog all over the place. In web applications, services and tools which run every once in a while

When a lot of servers are used and scalability is an issue, check this: http://developers.facebook.com/scribe/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using log4j or log4net for the logging, then you can watch the logs using [Apache Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html) which is a GUI that allows you to view the log by groups, kind, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [splunk](http://www.splunk.com) to view syslogs. It is free and has many reporting & visualization features for logs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of ELMAH myself, it doesn't log to syslog though, but provides very clean error logging facilities.

[Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)